# Solr upgrade 8.6 to 9.2

Tags: solr

This upgrade seems to have gone smoothly. solr.in.sh is configured correctly. However, the console page does not render.

Rolling back by pointing solr symlink to 8.6 allows 8.6 to run normally.

What type of things might cause 9.2 to work? Not sure what I am missing.

Here are my installation steps as taken from solr upgrade page:

1. systemctl stop solr
2. cd /opt
3. wget https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/solr/solr/9.2.1/solr-9.2.1.tgz
4. mv solr-9.2.1.tgz solr-9.2.1.tgz
5. tar xzf solr-9.2.1.tgz solr-9.2.1/bin/install_solr_service.sh --strip-components=2
6. bash install_solr_service.sh solr-9.2.1.tgz -f -u admin
7. chown -R admin:admin solr-9.2.1
8. systemctl start solr

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser's developer console? What does the Network tab show for the requests being made?